# Initializing DB rows in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, initialization, rows

I have some rows of data that I want to always exist in the database across all of the different environments we have. I don't want to put it in the seed file, because that wouldn't affect production database.

I was thinking of writing a new file in initializer and then inserting the rows in the database if they don't already exist. Is that typically what people do in Rails? Any tips or advice?

Comment: "that wouldn't affect the production database" how come?

Comment: what a about a regular rake task

Comment: You can use a migration to add the records. That way rails will complain if you did not run the migrationa and you don't add extra work on the initializers.

Comment: Why not put it in the seed file and simply run seeds in production?

Comment: @dbugger The seed file is not something we would want to run in production.... example maybe at the beginning before we had a ton of production data.